# How to get "Title" attribute from the "Page" object

Tags: silverstripe

I use SilverStripe as the CMS and I'm stuck now and don't know how to access "Title" attribute from the "Page" object.

I tried:

$Event.Trainer.Title

But it doesn't work. The "Trener" is the "TrenerPage" object. How can I access to Trener->Title attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You can't traverse three levels in SilverStripe templates (at least in version 2.x). Two is the maximum.

What you need is something like this:

```
<% control Event %>
    $Trainer.Title
<% end_control %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to inconsistently switch between "Trainer" and "Trener", I'm guessing one of those is a typo?

If the template is for the page you wish to display the title of, all you need to use is `$Title` in your template and it will output the title of the rendering page.

If the template is NOT for the page you wish to display the title of, then like xeraa said, you should use a control block.

Answer (score 0):

The title is directly within the Page object.
Just using $Title should do the trick. To help you with all the methods available in the Page object go to:
http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/built-in-page-controls

Since the question is not very clear, I'll take a shot at another answer.
If you derived the Trainer_Page from the Page object it still inherit the $Title attribute directly. Unless you overider the $Title attribute yourself in the Trainer_Page object, PHP will default it back to the parent class. In that case just use $Title.

Beware of the case as $title and $Title are not the same.

Good luck.